# Add labels and title to a plot made using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I made a simple histogram using the following code:

```py
a = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']
pd.Series(a).value_counts().plot('bar')
```

[image: barplot of counts]

Although this is a concise way to plot frequency histogram, I am not sure how to customize the plot i.e. :

1. Add Title
2. Add Axis Labels
3. Sort values on x-axis

Comment: check out the API for  [pandas.DataFrame.plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), from a quick look I see proper arguments for 1,2 and 3

Comment: `ax = pd.Series(a).value_counts().plot(kind='bar', title='I should read the docs', xlabel='xlabel', ylabel='ylabel')`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Series.plot` (or `DataFrame.plot`) returns a matplotlib `axis` object which exposes several methods.  For example:

```
a = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']
ax = pd.Series(a).value_counts().sort_index().plot('bar')
ax.set_title("my title")
ax.set_xlabel("my x-label")
ax.set_ylabel("my y-label")
```

[image: updated plot]

n.b.: pandas uses matplotlib as a dependency here, and is exposing matplotlib objects and api.  You can get the same result via `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; ax = plt.subplots(1,1,1)`.  If you ever create more than one plot at a time, you will find the `ax.<method>` far more convenient than the module level `plt.title('my title')`, because it defines *which* plot title you'd like to change and you can take advantage of autocomplete on the `ax` object.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `matplotlib` to customize it. You can see I used `.sort_index()` to sort the xlabels.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']
pd.Series(a).value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind='bar')
plt.title('My Title')
plt.xlabel('My X Label')
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you can now just use the `title`, `xlabel`, and `ylabel` parameters (and use the `kind` parameter for the plot type):

```
a = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'e']    
pd.Series(a).value_counts().plot(kind='bar', title="Your Title", xlabel="X Axis", ylabel="Y Axis")
```

See the [Pandas plot() docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.html) for more info.