# Change the GROUPED title (not "usual" plot title) of a pandas boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I created a boxplot out of a pandas df by running the following:

```
ax = df1.boxplot(column=['data1'], by=['category'], grid=False, figsize=(6,5))
```

and the resulting boxplot came with:

- a default title (ie. **grouped title**): "Boxplot grouped by category" --> see yellow
- a subtitle (what would be the "usual" title for other graph types): "data1" --> see green

[image]

When I tried to change the grouped title by passing the **title** argument into the boxplot function, this didn't work (although it's worked for other chart types like barh)

```
   ax = df1.boxplot(column=['data1'], by=['category'], grid=False, figsize=(6,5), title = 'my_title')
```

If we use the **ax.set_title()** approach as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63650646/add-labels-and-title-to-a-plot-made-using-pandas), it will change the **boxplot subtitle but NOT the grouped title.**

Please note that my question does not duplicate [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63650646/add-labels-and-title-to-a-plot-made-using-pandas), as that post's solution will only affect the subtitle instead of the grouped title, and I'm looking for a change in the **boxplot's grouped title**

Comment: Use `suptitle`:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507229/set-no-title-for-pandas-boxplot-groupby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `suptitle`

```
ax.get_figure().suptitle('My Title')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`plt.title`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.title.html) or [`ax.set_title`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_title.html) functions to set title.

Comment: Thank you for that, the ax.set_title option worked! But the plt.title one gave me the following error "AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'set_title'"

Comment: It's a function, you need to call it. `plt.title('Title')`